# Adding Function Auth to HTTP Function when Deploying through GitHub Actions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, github-actions

I have an Azure Function that I am developing locally in VS Code, and using the deployment pipeline through GitHub Actions.  When using this deployment pipeline, the function never actually shows up in the Functions tab of the Function App I have created.  Ok, fine, I can validate that the function and zip files get deployed, the GitHub actions all complete successfully, that's great.

The issue is coming from the authentication I want to enforce for the HTTP function.  I want to use Function level authentication for the HTTP request.  The Microsoft docs all say to go to your function in the Azure Portal in the Function App, click the function, and then assign a key to it using the Function Keys option on the left.

This would be great, except that it appears because of the deployment pipeline method I'm using, the function doesn't appear in the functions list, so there is nothing to click into and issue a key.

Is there something I'm missing here about how to enforce this level of authorization when using this deployment pipeline?  Should the function be showing up in the functions list, even if I deploy with this method?  Am I supposed to generate the function key using the CLI since it is not available in the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps to deploy Azure Function to function app using GitHub actions:

1. Create a repository in GitHub and push your function code to it.

- open command prompt=> go to root folder of your project and run below commands:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin <your_repository_url>
git push -u origin main
```

2. Create an Azure function with the required features (OS, runtime stack) in Portal.

Before starting the deployment process, add the settings `SCM_DO-BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true` and `ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD=true` in Function app=>Settings=>Configuration=>Add Application Setting.

[image]

- Open your function app=>go to Deployment=> Deployment Center=>Select *GitHub* as *Source* and fill the remaining fields accordingly.

[image]

- Once you submit this action=> It will generate an yaml file with the workflow to deploy function to azure using github actions.

***My Workflow:***

```
name: Build and deploy Node.js project to Azure Function App - <functionapp_name>

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.' 
  NODE_VERSION: '18.x' 

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: 'Checkout GitHub Action'
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Node ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }} Environment
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }}

      - name: 'Resolve Project Dependencies Using Npm'
        shell: bash
        run: |
          pushd './${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}'
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
          popd

      - name: 'Run Azure Functions Action'
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: fa
        with:
          app-name: '<functionapp_name>'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_62XXXXXXX }}
```

- You can track the deployment status in the *Logs* Section.

[image]

- This way you can deploy the function to Azure function app.

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

To use function level authentication, as you mentioned above click on the deployed *function=> Developer =>Function Keys=>Add New function key* and assign value as shown below:

[image]

Comment: This seemed to work, and the deployment logs all support that the function is up and running.  Then I go to look at functions there is still nothing there and I have the following warning at the top of the functions screen.  Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting.

Comment: Set `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1` in application settings of function app.

Comment: This is a ZIP deploy using Python on Linux, should I have {WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=0} and {WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_ZIP=1}

Comment: `Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting`. This is just a warning. You have to add `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_ZIP=1` for zip deployment. Refer [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package#using-website_run_from_package--1).

Comment: Thank you for the help.  This, and a combination of the folder structure being off were my problems!